# For loop to put the data in array

Tags: typescript

I have the following JSON :

```
{
 a : 10,
 b : 20,
 c : 30
}
```

I want the data in following array

```
var label =['a','b','c']
var value = ['10','20','30']
```

How can I achieve the same in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
let obj = { a : 10, b : 20, c : 30 };

let labels = Object.keys(obj);

let values = labels.map(key => obj[key]);
```

The first lines extracts the property names in an array. Next we use this array to retrieve each value in another separate array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), so you only iterate over the object once:

```js
const data = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 30,
};

const extracted = Object.entries(data)
  .reduce(
    (existing, entry) => {
      const { labels, values } = existing;
      const [ label, value ] = entry;

      return {
        labels: [...labels, label],
        values: [...values, value],
      }
    },
    {
      labels: [],
      values: [],
    }
  );
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uptymsz3/) to play around with it.